# android: ScrollView in 1.5 doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview

My one layout works perfect on 1.6+ but throws error on 1.5 and results in shutting down the app with "Force Close". The layout contains RelativeLayout as parent, ScrollView which contains RelativeLayout as child and imagevite, textview, edittext, buttons in child relativeLayout. Here's the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/user_pswd_new_root" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true">

 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollViewLogin" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:visibility="visible">
   <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:background="@drawable/logo_login_new" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/login_text" android:layout_marginRight="40dp" 
    android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:text="@string/username" android:id="@+id/textView2_usr" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2_usr" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2_usr" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:id="@+id/user_pwd_username"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_below="@+id/user_pwd_username" android:id="@+id/textView3_usr" android:text="@string/password"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3_usr" android:layout_below="@+id/user_pwd_username" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user_pwd_username" android:id="@+id/user_pwd_password" android:password="true"></EditText>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/user_pwd_password" android:text="@string/remMe" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:id="@+id/user_pwd_remMeChk"></CheckBox>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/user_pwd_remMeChk" android:text="@string/loginBtn" android:id="@+id/user_pwd_btn_ok" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" android:width="100dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/user_pwd_btn_cancel" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="40dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_pwd_btn_ok" android:text="@string/cancelBtn" android:width="100dp"></Button>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Version" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_below="@+id/user_pwd_btn_cancel" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:id="@+id/versionText" android:textSize="6dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/versionText" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:id="@+id/messageText" android:scrollbars="vertical"></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>        

</RelativeLayout>
```

The errors I get in LogCat is :

```
05-17 17:07:02.110: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception             
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{orange.android.vpn/orange.android.vpn.StartUltimate}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor  
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:400)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at orange.android.myw.LoginDialog.init(LoginDialog.java:78)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at orange.android.myw.LoginDialog.<init>(LoginDialog.java:72)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at orange.android.vpn.StartUltimate.onCreate(StartUltimate.java:129)
 05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
 05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 11 more
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:103)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 25 more
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1641)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1725)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:107)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 29 more
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:392)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1634)
05-17 17:07:02.139: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1215):     ... 32 more
```

Error points to setContentView() line in the LoginDialog class.
Can anyone tell what is stopping it to show up in 1.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLution :

The image on which the error is locating i.e. "0x7f020005" which is a .png image. 1.5 doesn't recognize png images in drawable-hdpi or any, it looks in /drawable folder. I created a drawable folder in /res and copied the png image to it and the screen showed up. But due to small screen size, everything is one upon other. I tried with android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" attribute in ScrollView, but it only works vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling doesn't work. What to do with this problem (Scroll Horizontal) now ?

Comment: I have the same problem, but tried to put "scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png" to "res/drawable", but the same error still occurs. What png image have you copied there?

Answer (score 0):

The very first exception is a FileNotFoundException. Check if the file `res/drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png` does exist.

Comment: Nothing like this is there in my drawable. Previously also it wasn't there. Don't know from where it is looking these files.

Comment: You should check your R file, if it contains that file variable. Try to clean your project to get the R regenerated.

Comment: Had tried that earlier also. Tried agian with Project - Clean, started new emu and tried, but same results.

Comment: does your R file contains that drawable?

Comment: No.     public static final class drawable {
        public static final int connect_ico=0x7f020000;
        public static final int disconnect_ico=0x7f020001;
        public static final int icon=0x7f020002;
        public static final int iconold=0x7f020003;
        public static final int logo_login=0x7f020004;
        public static final int logo_login_new=0x7f020005;
        public static final int small_icon=0x7f020006;
    }

Comment: I just saw that the emulator created by Eclipse has no hardware listed not even "LCD density". Does that affect in any way? I don't think it does but ....

Comment: Hm... maybe you should try to use a new created AVD. Maybe your current one is corrupted...

Comment: No WarrenFaith, that's also not the problem. The image on which the error is locating i.e. "0x7f020005" which is a .png image. 1.5 doesn't recognize png images in drawable-hdpi or any, it looks in /drawable folder. I created a drawable folder in /res and copied the png image to it and the screen showed up. 

But due to small screen size, everything is one upon other. I tried with android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" attribute in ScrollView, but it only works vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling doesn't work. 
What to do with this problem (Scroll Horizontal) now ?